# OutputCache VaryByContentEncodings gzip doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, encoding, outputcache

I've set the OutputCache to include 'VaryByContentEncodings="gzip"' in my ASP.net ASPX page. I want the page to serve different css files, a gzipped if the browser support it and the regular non compressed if the browser doesn't support compression.

Example:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="320" VaryByParam="none" VaryByContentEncodings="gzip"  %>
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

*The 'varybycontentencodings' attribute is not supported by the 'outputcache' directive in a page.*

I don't know what's the problem and why it doesn't work. Second, do you think that by serving different gzip/non-compressed CSS I'm doing the right thing. Just note that the files are served from Amazon S3, so I can't rely on IIS or .NET engine to return the compressed files automatically. That's why I want to serve to separate cached version of the page.

In this it seems to be ok, but it doesn't work (using ASP.NET 4.5):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachevarybycontentencodings.aspx

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Funny mistake, I've just forgot to put the **Location** attribute and therefore I've got an error. However, Microsoft put this code on their website, and that lead me to think that this code should work AS IS.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachepolicy.varybycontentencodings.aspx

Answer (score 4):

- What version is
  your app pool running?
- Is the directive in a page, control or
  masterpage?

> VaryByContentEncodings is introduced in the .NET Framework version
>   3.5.

[HttpCachePolicy.VaryByContentEncodings Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachepolicy.varybycontentencodings.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I just had exactly the same problem. The problem is - Visual Studio intellisense suggests you an incorrect attribute name. The correct one, is "**VaryByContentEncoding**" - withough the "s" in the end.

Correct:

```
<%@ OutputCache ... VaryByContentEncoding="gzip"  %>
```

Incorrect:

```
<%@ OutputCache ... VaryByContentEncodings="gzip"  %>
```